# How to flow type a function that takes in a class and outputs another class?

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

I've got a function that wraps a given class with some helpers, but I don't know how to annotate it using Flow.

```
class SomeClass<T> {
  a:T
}

// Erroneous flow annotations here
const Wrapper = (SuperClass: Class<SomeClass>) : Class<SomeClass> => {
  return class NewClass<Props> extends SuperClass<Props>{
    helper(){}
  }
}

const Wrapped = Wrapper(SomeClass)

class ExtendedClass extends Wrapped<number>{
}

let actual = new ExtendedClass()
actual.a = 1234
```

Ironically, if I take out the flow annotations from the wrapping function, it actually works perfectly fine, but I'd like to figure out how to do it myself so I can be explicit and limit the arguments to subclasses of `SomeClass`.